# Conjugacy classes of elementary abelian subgroups of rank $2$ does the Heisenberg group have?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number and $G=GL_n ( \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}
)$. The Heisenberg group $U_{n}$  is the set of upper-triangular matrices of $G$
having entries of $1$ on the diagonal.  $U_{n}$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^{\frac {n(n-1)} 2}$, in particular $U_{n}$ is a
Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. It is well known that the Sylow $p$-subgroups of the group $G$ are conjugate, and every $p$-subgroup $H$ of $G$ is contained in
some Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then there exists $g\in G$ such that  $H\leq
gUg^{-1}$.

**Questions:**

1. How many sylow $p$-subgroup does $G=GL_n ( \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}
   )$ have?.
2. what is the number of conjugacy classes of elementary abelian subgroups of order $p^2$ in $U_{n}$.

   Any help would be appreciated so much. Thank you all.

Comment: Question 1 is easy, because the normaliser of $U_n$ in $G$ consists of the upper triangular matrices, so $|N_G(U_n):U_n| = (p-1)^n$. Question 2 is much more difficult - there are lots of them. For example, by computer calculation, there are $67$ classes ofor $(n,p) = (4,3)$ and $13115$ classes for $(n,p)=(5,5)$.